# USER Update with new role into database with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am facing problem with updating/edit user with new role assigned or changed role from (1 or 2). Role remains same with NO Exception or Error.

**NOTE:** I am posting screenshots here as I want to show exactly what I am seeing.

I have a `User` class with role and city associated classes in it:

```
public class User
{   
    public City CityId { get; set; }

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }

    public bool IsInRole(int id)
    {
        return Role != null && Role.Id == id;
    }       
}
```

The `Role` table has only 2 roles, Admin with ID=1 and guest with ID=2.

[image: roleDBTable]

I am facing problem with updating the role of an existing user.

What I am trying to do here is I want to give admin rights to a user by simply updating the user and pass 1 in role field as shown here:

[image: View]  [image: Typed-View]

I am able to pass 1 or 2 id through this field into controller and manage to get "admin" by role id:

[image: controller]

As I am have the desired ROLE object in USER :

[image: dbcontext]

I'm still unable to update user with Admin role in database. It still has `Guest` role id.

Same scenario is with the `CityID` in the `User` class.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why are you setting DbEntityEntry.State to Unchanged? Comment those statements and it should work.

Comment: @DipenShah: i added them later. it is not updating in both cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The thing is you have to find the id first then make it sure the Role
>   table should be unmodified:

```
public void Update(User users // this is your object`enter code here)
{
    using(_db)
    {
        User user= db.User.Find(users.id);
        user.Role_id = users.Role_id; // this is what you want to change.
        _db.Entry(Role).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

> Hope That will Help. Cheers

Comment: Yes this is exactly the answer i was finding!
Thank You!

Comment: Actually i dont need to set unchange to Role class directly. i had to set 
`_db.Entry(user.Role_id).State = EntityState.Unchanged; `

Answer (score 2):

You need to find the ID of that specific user like:

```
public void UserEdit(int?id //id is your parameter here)
{
   //This is what you need.

    User user= db.User.Find(id);
    user.Role = //this is the new Role if this user
    user.CityId = //city id here
}
```

Update user:

```
public void UpdateUser(User user)
{
   db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
   db.SaveChanges();

}
```

You need the user table not the role table..

//Sample class

```
public class User_Table
{   
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    public int RoleID { get; set; }
}
```

This table is the one you need to update not the role table as your sample from above.

Comment: Model is strongly bind with View already.  i dont need to find that user again. More over except these two, my all other fields (like: name, address, phone, email etc) are properly updating with the same code through same action.

Comment: I try your logic ! but,
first i had to include role and city when i am finding a user of that specific Id because role and city had separate tables and are connected through foreign key relation...  still  after doing that the results are same. no change ni role in User table.

Comment: you need to update the user table not the role table.. Your page is just pointing of the specific user which is the role id and city id. Your user class is not the table for updating.Hope you got me.

Comment: Yes i got you. Actually i write only role and city property here. As mention above that only these two are associated classes else are normal properties in user class , Name , Phone# , etc etc . I AM UPDATING the EXISTING user having GUEST role TO ADMIN role. by assigning or passing ADMIN role id which is 1.

Comment: GOT  IT! i dont know why i always have to find user again for update . and set values from user object to another user object. but it works.

Answer (score 1):

You Pass the Full Object of User it will change the state of Another Table that Why First Take the User Object As it is After Changing the Data Store In to Another NEw Object and Then UPDate AND state keep unchanged of ROle Table
I Hope It Work Well

```
 public ActionResult UpdateUser(User newUser)
    {
        newUser.City = new City { Id = Convert.ToInt32(fdata["CityList"]) };
        dbcontext db = new dbcontext();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (db)
            {
                User oldUser = db.Users.Find(newUser.Id);
                oldUser.Role = newUser.Role;

                db.Entry(newUser.Role).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return View();
            }
```